# Failed to copy VS2015 project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to copy/backup a Visual Studio 2015 project? Copying files in Explorer doesn't work, and I didn't see options in VS to copy/save-as the project.

Comment: I am a Java person (though I have used VS before), but I would imagine if you copy the root project folder it should work.  Which files did you actually copy?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen All files are copied, but all files of the new project in VS are linked to the old ones.